# XML Subviews lost on site navigation

Tags: sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I created a [simple SAPUI5 Application](https://github.com/anasnakawa/ui5views) that can be deployed as a widget to SAP HANA Cloud Portal. 
this Application contain one root xml view, that loads two nested xml views, and does not have any complex logic inside it.

On SAP HANA Cloud Portal, when this widget is added to multiple pages on the same site, everything looks good.
But once you start to navigate between site pages, the root xml view will loose its sub views html.

Since the application does not contain any complex logic, why does the root view loose those sub views ?

And how can I maintain sub view content after site navigation occurs ?

The root view code as follows:

```
<mvc:View controllerName="ui5views.controller.RootApp" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m">
  <mvc:XMLView id="renderView" viewName="ui5views.view.render" />
  <mvc:XMLView id="editView" viewName="ui5views.view.edit" />
</mvc:View>
```

And sub views are:

1. edit.view.xml

   ```
   <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="ui5views.controller.render"
   xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <VBox id="app" class="app-root-edit">
       <html:div id="appEdit" class="app-edit">edit</html:div>
   </VBox>
   ```
2. render.view.xml

   ```
   <mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="ui5views.controller.render"
   xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <VBox id="app" class="app-root-view">
       <html:div id="appViewer" class="app-viewer">render</html:div>
   </VBox>
   ```

Full Sample Application Source available on Github: https://github.com/anasnakawa/ui5views

**To reproduce the issue, follow these steps:**

1. Clone the [repo](https://github.com/anasnakawa/ui5views) into SAP Web IDE
2. Deploy to SAP HANA Cloud Portal
3. Create a Site on SAP HCP
4. Create another site page
5. Add ui5views to the first page
6. Inspect the widget, and look for any sub view ( `.app-viewer` or `.app-edit` )
7. Navigate to the other site page, and add ui5views widget
8. Navigate back to first page

**Expected Results:**

Subviews will remain inside the root view

**Actual Results:**

Subviews are not inside root view ( `document.querySelectorAll( '.app-viewer' )` will show that views are placed somewhere else on the page )